# MS Teams Bot oAuthPrompt, how to change popup size

Tags: authentication, botframework, size, microsoft-teams, popupwindow

I would like to know how to control the size of the popup of a ms-teams oauthPrompt.

I'm writing a Teams bot that includes sso to my application.

I followed the examples such as '46.teams-auth', and have two services running: ms-teams-bot, auth-service

```
AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
  nameof(OAuthPrompt),
    new OAuthPromptSettings
      {
        ConnectionName = ConnectionName,
        Text = "Please Sign In",
        Title = "Sign In",
        Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login (1000 * 60 * 5)
      }));
```

Everything is working except I don't know how to control the size of the popup that opens once I click the sign in button in the oAuthPrompt.

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-bot) article that notes I can add width/height to the URL to control the popup size, but I don't understand which URL they are referring to.
I have set the URL to my auth-service on Azure on the 'Service Provider Connection Setting
', adding width/size to this doesn't affect the popup size, and the URL of the 'Sign In' button is not controlled by me.

Answer (score 1):

You need pass width and height query string parameters in the URL. Please see the below code.

```
microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
    url: window.location.origin + "/tab-auth/simple-start",
    width: 600,
    height: 535,
    successCallback: function (result) {
        getUserProfile(result.accessToken);
    },
    failureCallback: function (reason) {
        handleAuthError(reason);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't have any code that similar's this.
I don't call microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({...

Comment: I didn't implement SSO authentication, I am using the oauthPrompt, the URL of the Login button is not controlled by me.
Do I need to override something ?

Comment: @PeterGreen - Adding width/size doesn't effect the popup size. I have raised a bug for this issue and concerned team is working on it.